# Bootstrap jumbotron thumbnails break in Firefox/IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

On http://www.bier-in-aktion.at I have jumbotron including boottrap divs with class thumbnail (brand pictures).
In Chrome the site and thumbnail behaviour works just fine. In Firefox and IE it doesn't. Issues:

- left align doesn't take place (it seems to align the thumbnails
  right)
- last element coming out of this foreach loop (now it's Kaiser
  Bier) positions completely-flow-unlogic (at least for me :)).

It's programmed as follows:

1. set div.row
2. loop all brands and insert a div with class "col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"
3. close div.row

So you can see that - in terms of bootstrap row-thinking - this is not 100 % perfect in terms of -> one div.row for one thumbnail line. I tried to deny that due to a more complicated foreach loop logic regarding closing divs + in Chrome it works fine.

Do you have an idea how this can be solved effiecient? Many thx in advance!

Comment: I have no Idea what exactly is going on in Firefox, but something about the title Ottakringer clears the float. If you remove the title in the Web Inspector, the boxes float correctly.

Comment: Well, as I just said, something about the button "Ottakringer" breaks the float. Which is even more strange considering there is no clearing involved in any of the elements. It seems that the height of this particular block is calculated differently. Since you cant set a fixed height, implementing this list of elements as inline-blocks will work better than floats. Have a look at this mozdev article: https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: thank you @j4k3! That has been the issue. So what I did: Removed the buttons + edited the logo with similar size to the neigboring logo pics. That was it ... Never would have found that out. If you find time, can you tell me how you recognized that?